# Changing color in foreach loop

Tags: pgfplots, color

I am trying to plot 12 different lines with a for loop and with a gradually changing color.
I came up with this simple code:

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ylabel={Normalized Intensity (a.u.)},
    xlabel={Energy (eV)},
    ]
        \foreach \column in {1,...,12}{
            \addplot[style = solid, color = red!\column!black] table[x index = {0}, y index = {\column}] {../Data/12spectra.asc};
        }
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{blablablabla}
\end{figure}
```

but the command red!\column!black does not work. I thought that the keyword \column would have been substituted at each occurrence with its value...
The error I get is

```
!Undefined control sequence.
\GenericError ...
#4 \errhelp \@err@ ...
l.75 \end{axis}
```

I have seen this question [Changing color in foreach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251300/changing-color-in-foreach), but it didn't help me.

I have included only the pgfplots package, do I need another one?

Do you have any suggestion on how to fix the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use instead `pgfplotsinvokeforeach` such that the value is expanded

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ylabel={Normalized Intensity (a.u.)},
    xlabel={Energy (eV)},
    ]
        \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,...,12}{
            \addplot[style = solid, color = red!#1!black] table[x index = {0}, y index = {#1}] {../Data/12spectra.asc};
        }
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Also don't use names that are very likely to be keywords in some packages such as `\column`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works very well!
If I wanted to change the color range, could I use something like \pgfmathparse{#1*8} and \pgfmathresult?

Comment: edit: I solved with using color = {rgb,12:red,#1;green,1;blue,1};
Thanks again for the answer!