# Color names in foreach loop

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, loops, foreach

**Edit: I can't delete this question despite it being based on a silly mistake. Please don't waste time reading/answering.**

---

I'm trying to draw a row of boxes which alternate colours, and I'm using a `\foreach` to do it. My question is whether it's possible to use colour names as a variable in a `foreach` loop.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \foreach \x/\y {1/blue, 2/red, 3/blue, 4/red}
    \fill[color=\y] (\x,0) --++ (1,0) --++ (0,1) --++ (-1,0) --cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

When I run this I get the error `! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/pgf/foreach/color', to which you passed '\y ', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.`

In other questions I've seen ([example 1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/297634/changing-color-in-foreach-loop), [example 2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251300/changing-color-in-foreach), [example 3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/283934/changing-color-in-foreach-using-arrayjob)), people have been asking about defining colours with numbers (`red!50!black`, for example), so I think this question is different.

So, am I just doing something wrong, or is it simply not possible to do what I'm trying to do. If it's the latter, I'll do it a different way,  but I wanted to know about the possibility.

Comment: Haha, I usually find this SE forum to have the nicest community! When someone makes a silly mistake on others like SO they'll get downvoted and then forced to delete their post.

Answer (score 11):

`\foreach \x/\y in {..}`. You forgot `in`.

By the way, it's a bit shorter with `rectangle`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \foreach \x/\y in {1/blue, 2/red, 3/blue, 4/red}
    \fill[color=\y] (\x,0) rectangle +(1,1);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: "You forgot in." Ooh dear. That's embarrassing.

Answer (score 7):

A slightly different approach:

- you don't need `color=` in your fill command
- maybe a single loop while counting another variable is simpler

---

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\foreach \y [count=\x] in {blue, red, blue, red} {
  \fill[\y] (\x,0) --++ (1,0) --++ (0,1) --++ (-1,0) --cycle;
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe with `\ifodd` it would be even nicer... (+1)

Comment: @marmot Thanks for your vote :) If the colours are strictly alternating, `\ifodd` is certainly the much easier way.